# How does 斡旋 mean "to mediate"?

Tags: etymology, word

I'm studying CCTV news with my Chinese teacher, where I encountered the word 斡旋 for the first time:

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%96%A1%E6%97%8B): 斡旋 (wò​xuán​) to mediate (a conflict etc)
>
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%96%A1): 斡 (wò​) to turn
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%97%8B): 旋 (​xuán​) to revolve / a loop / a circle

I'm familiar with words containing 旋, like 盘旋 = "to spiral" and 旋涡 = "whirlpool".  My 现代汉语词典 dictionary suggests 斡 is largely only used in the word 斡旋.  I didn't find anything useful on [Dong Chinese](https://www.dong-chinese.com/wiki/%E6%96%A1) aside from 斡 being a rather rare character.

I'm fairly sure I'll forget this word in about 10 minutes time.  In any case, it'd help me remember if I understood the underlying logic: currently it doesn't seem to make much sense "to turn" + "to revolve" = "to mediate".

**Question**: How does 斡旋 mean "to mediate"?

Comment: When I was a kid, I often heard the term "中東挖船" or "從中挖船" on news and thought 挖船 must be a transliteration of "rush"  and "rush" must contain the meaning of "mediate". Thanks to this post, now I finally realize it was 中東斡旋 (The Middle East mediation) not "中東挖船" (ship digging  in the Middle East) and  it is "從中斡旋" (mediate in-between) not "從中挖船"(digging ship in-between)

Comment: Nowadays the term 斡旋 is rarely used on news, the common term for "mediate" now is 調停

Comment: I think the most appropriate translation for 斡旋 is "circle around" or "navigate". It's basically the same as 周旋 which means keeping distance from all participants and trying to keep a balance between you and the whole system.

Answer (score 5):

The subject to be "mediated" is naturally "conflict"

To turn and revolve around (the conflicted parties) = to mediate (the conflict)

Example:

为中美贸易冲突**斡旋** - **Mediating** the US-China trade conflict

*The mediator has to go back and forth between the Chinese and the American government to Mediate the conflict*

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays this is a rather official word used in situations between two countries. Actually, it is rarely used. People using it may just show that they were well educated.
Anyway, I think it's OK that you just forget it.